# Angular Material Nested Drag and Drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material2

I'm trying to achieve a reorder-able group of list which contain elements that can be moved between lists, using @angular/cdk/drag-drop, although I'm running into a few problems.

I've managed to separately create individual examples which achieve the individual drag and drop, although when brought together it seems I cannot achieve both pieces of functionality in parallel.

**Moving items between groups**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/items-move

**Reordering groups**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/groups-move

**Both together**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/groups-items-move

It seems in the **Both together** example, the dragging of individual items works as expected, but the re-ordering of the groups does not work, however, the `cdkDropListGroup` on line 4 of `cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.html` when moved outside the parent `<cdk-drop-list>` then causes the opposite to occur, the groups are now able to be reordered, but the items are then not able to be moved between groups.

Any pointer as to where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16671

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like cdkDropListGroup doesn't work for nested lists.
Just add the id to the lists and connect them together with [cdkDropListConnectedTo].

**Both together**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-connected-lists

Comment: Do you know why id is required?

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! A small addition: it's better to add cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" to the outer cdkDropList to get rid of that moving of the groups up and down.

Comment: Any idea of how to make it work for nesting groups, ie we should be able to insert a group within a group . ?

Comment: I was able to achieve the same with solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-nested-drag-drop-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fcomponents%2Flist-item%2Flist-item.html   , but couldnt get both the reordering and nesting to work correctly,  i had to give a separate holder for dragging to group and changing the order.

Comment: @Stalli     ..Any idea with this?

Comment: Note that it is literally by design that this doesn't work automatically with `cdkDropListGroup`. In the source you can see that CDK_DROP_LIST_GROUP is redefined as undefined to prevent inheriting it.

Comment: @Stalli Do anyone of you know how to achieve dragging and dropping multiple items with checkboxes to select?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for nested drag/drop with material accordion along with below points.

1. In List parent to parent drag/drop
2. In List inside one parent child to child drag/drop
3. In List one child from one parent to other parent drag/drop

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hhnnke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html