# Angular Material nested drag and drop *FOR UNKNOWN NUMBER OF cdkDragLists

Tags: angular, nested, drag-and-drop, angular-material

I am trying to do drag and drop in an angular application where I have 2 lists, one on the right and one on the left. [Here is a crude visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fYfN.png)

I need to be able to drag (and copy) items from the left group to lists on the right which are separated by groups. In this case I am dragging the *list item*.

I also need to be able to reorder the list items within their groups and switch them between groups on the right side. This much I have working.

**WHAT I NEED** is to be able to reorder the GROUPS that hold the list items.

I'm guessing I have this issue because I used `cdkDropListGroup`. It automatically connects any of the list groups and I cannot individually drag the items while still being able to grab the whole groups as a group. I tried refactoring to use the

```
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="list-one"
```

but because I am rendering an unpredictable amount of groups AND i need them to still be connected so that I can drag between the groups, it will not let me connect the lists by ID.

Am I just out of luck for essentially nesting WITHIN the cdkDropListGroup tag or is there a way to handle this I am not seeing?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075606/angular-material-nested-drag-and-drop/54386834#54386834) is a question VERY similar to what I am asking... I would just comment on the answer that was given (which was inadequate in my case) but I do not have the reputation to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use $event within (cdkDropListDropped). Essentially you can achieve the [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="list-one" by mapping the transferArrayItem between the two lists. As far as the unpredictable amount of groups as long as your $event is emitting for each list you should be fine with *ngFor implementation

**TS:**

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
          transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                            event.container.data,
                            event.previousIndex,
                            event.currentIndex);
        }
      }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
```