# Ionic Angular ion-reorder-group inside ion-reorder-group

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="reorderGroup($event)" disabled="false">
  <ion-item>
    <label>Group 1</label>
    <ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="reorderRow1($event)" disabled="false">
      <ion-item>Row 1<ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder></ion-item>
      <ion-item>Row 2<ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder></ion-item>
    </ion-reorder-group>
    <ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <label>Group 2</label>
    <ion-reorder-group (ionItemReorder)="reorderRow2($event)" disabled="false">
      <ion-item>Row 1<ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder></ion-item>
      <ion-item>Row 2<ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder></ion-item>
    </ion-reorder-group>
    <ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder>
  </ion-item>
</ion-reorder>
```

This is working fine but when I try to drag the item for rows also the group item move..
My question is How can I prevent the group item from moving when I move the row item.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I am currently checking this... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075606/angular-material-nested-drag-and-drop?rq=1
but its better if I use ion-reorder-group if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone is looking for angular nested reorder try this..
@angular/cdk/drag-drop https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview
I use this instead of ion-reorder because I cant find nested ion-reorder...
Other user deleted this answer but this is the solution that helps me and it may help others.